# Set toolbar icons size in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio

I've just installed an update to android studio and now I see version `3.0.1`
When I look to a toolbar I see that icons became two times smaller than usual.

[image]

Is it possible to make them bigger as it was before?

Answer (score 11):

As said in [this comment](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69571503#comment7) it is an Intended Behavior in version 3.0.  But this behavior can be reverted by setting the system property `hidpi.allow.fractional` to `true` in file `~AndroidStudioHOME\idea.properties` and restart Android Studio.

You can open and edit this file directly from IDE by **Help | Edit Custom Properties** menu:

```
hidpi.allow.fractional=true
```

P.S. But, for example, I'm already used to this size and it seems to me quite comfortable. There is more space for text, especially at 13 inches laptop.

**Update** Fixed in Android Studio 3.1. Icons become bigger as earlier

Answer (score 7):

Have the same issue after updating to 3.0.1. As of [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69571503), it seems like a known issue & it is in assigned state. For a temporary fix, we can adjust the UI font of Android Studio from settings as below.

1. File -> Settings
2. Appearance & Behavior -> Appearance
3. Under **UI Options**, select Override default fonts
4. Set the size (I am setting size 24 to make the icons & text bigger)

> Note : The above steps will make the Android Studio UI ugly but until
>   a patch is released, we might need to adjust to this.

Answer (score 0):

After I used to the small icons there's a surprise after update to Android Studio 3.1. Icons became big again :)

[image]