# Android Studio update 3.0.1 made everything tiny

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated Android Studio from version 3.0 to 3.0.1 and I encountered an unexpected error: the entire UI shrunk to unusable size. We're talking buttons, icons, text, the whole bit. The text size in the editor remains unaffected, but my buttons like "debug" and "avd manager" are now about half the size of my mouse pointer, if not smaller.

So is this a config I need to change? I reset to defaults on everything I could find to no avail. Has anyone else experienced this? What can be done?

Notes: On on Windows 10, I have a dual-monitor setup (problem exists on both), the window title bar is (obviously) unaffected, and all I did to get here was click the "update" prompt in the bottom right of Android Studio when it started. Everything was fine at that time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set toolbar icons size in Android Studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400248/set-toolbar-icons-size-in-android-studio-3-0-1)

Answer (score 1):

Since AndroidStudio is based on IntelliJ, I searched a bit and found this on IntelliJ's support pages: [Troubleshooting IDE scaling issues on Windows](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001260010-Troubleshooting-IDE-scaling-DPI-issues-on-Windows).

Check it out, I hope it helps.

Comment: That's very interesting. It does indeed affect things, but not quite the way I would like. The font sizes up to 20 have no change or almost no change on the button size while increasing font sizes in most areas successfully. The jump to 22 (the next size up from 20) makes everything unusably enormous.